# Fit image to screen

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to simply display an image and have it autoscale to fit the screen. According to the docs `resizeMode: 'contain'` should do what I want. However, nothing I've tried seems to work. I've tried manually setting the width and height. I've tried setting them to `undefined`. I've tried using `Dimensions.get("window").height` but no matter what the image is not resized and it runs off the bottom and right side of the screen.

Here is the original image:
[image: Original image]

Here is how it gets rendered:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<View>
   <Image source={require('../../images/wireframe-car.jpg')} style={{resizeMode: 'contain'}} />
</View>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @R.Duteil Do I specify the actual width & height of the image or the width & height I would like it scaled to?

Comment: the resizeMode prop isn't a style value. However, you can use it with `<Image resizeMode="contain" ...otherProps />`

Comment: @kent the values you would like your image to scale to

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can achieve by add more `maxWidth` and `maxHeight`

```
 const {width, height} = Dimensions.get("window")
 render() {
   return(
    <View>
      <Image source={require('../../images/wireframe-car.jpg')}
        resizeMode='contain'
        style={{
          maxHeight: height,
          maxWidth: width
          }} />
    </View>
   )
 }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Except if I rotate the device it doesn't render properly unless I go out and come back in. Any idea how to make it refresh automatically when the screen dimensions change?

Comment: I used this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation to detect event when phone rotated. is case landscape you will need use `        style={{
          maxHeight: width,
          maxWidth: height
          }} />` just swap width, height

Comment: You are missing quotes. it's `maxHeight: 'height',  maxWidth: 'width'`

Answer (score 4):

Try something like that :

```
<View>
   <Image
       source={require('../../images/wireframe-car.jpg')}
       resizeMode={"contain"}
       style={{height: 100}}
   />
</View>
```

You have to set either width or height when using resizeMode, as it is not a style prop

Answer (score 2):

Make a container with whatever height and width you want and then use flex to fill it.

```
<View style={styles.imageContainer}
   <Image 
      source={require(../../images/wireframe-car.jpg)}
      resizeMode={"cover"}
      style={styles.image}
   />  
</View>

const styles = {
imageContainer: {
width: '100%',
height: 200
}
image: {
flex: 1
}
```